# How to avoid conflict with AQL in ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb, aql

I am using AQL to update records in a collection. Sometimes, I get [ArangoError 1200: conflict]. 
In JS Shell I can set the 3rd parameter as true to use overwrite and ignore the conflict. How do I ignore conflict in AQL?

Comment: Can you supply an example query that produces a conflict?

Comment: Did the the answer suit your needs? If yes, can  you mark it solved? If not, whats missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though I am not sure what causes the conflict, many query errors can be turned off by appending the directive `OPTIONS { ignoreErrors: true }` to the `UPDATE` part of the query.

For example, the following original query

```
FOR doc IN collection
  FILTER doc.value == 'someValue'  
  UPDATE doc WITH { count : doc.count + 1 } IN collection
```

would be adjusted to

```
FOR doc IN collection
  FILTER doc.value == 'someValue'  
  UPDATE doc WITH { count : doc.count + 1 } IN collection OPTION { ignoreErrors: true }
```

Though suppressing errors may hide relevant issues that exist in a query, so I wouldn't recommend it in general.